# Start function on a button in frame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code which open a frame. In the main frame i have a button that open frame2 (Page01). On page01 is a button which i would like make it call "function1" which is defined on top (and it's started when i open program, but i don t want this) and in the function1 i want call function2 which is defined in Page01.

```
Code

import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import ttk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

def function1():
    print "Function 1 started"
    #function2()

class ChangePages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainPage, Page01):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        def C(*args): return partial(self.option_changed, *args)

        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='top')

        btnpage01=Button(f,text='Go to Pag 01',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',18),height=1, width=10,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page01))
        btnpage01.grid(row=1,column=1)

class Page01(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        def function2():
            print "Function 2 started"

        bttest = Button(f,text='Start f',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1,width=10,command=function1() )
        bttest.grid(row=1,column=1)

#Root loop
app = ChangePages()
app.geometry('300x200+0+0')
app.title('Title ')
app.mainloop()
```

So what i want is to :
1- open program - function1 should not start, neither function2
2- open page01 - also function1 and 2 are stopped
3- press Start f and now function1 should start and also will cal function2 to start

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you need to remove the parentheses from `command=function1()`. Second, as it is now `function2` is local to `Page01`'s `__init__`, so you can't call it from anywhere else. I think you should read up on [classes and scopes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) before you try to do stuff like this.

Comment: Also `function` are object and can be passed as parameters so you can create a widget giving him a function to call under certain circumstance.